# Ajax Quiz or Ajaxify my site

Tags: 7, ajax, quiz

im using Drupal 7 and the Quiz module for making some quick courses.

It works fine, but i would love to make them with ajax transitions instead of doing it by the old form way.

I have seen the ajax quiz module, but it doesnt seem to work. any other recommendation? there's any other module i could use in order to ajaxify my quizzes or my whole site? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Quiz Drag Drop](https://drupal.org/project/quiz_drag_drop) module

> This module allow you to add drag drop type of question in quiz
>   module.
>
> By using this module admin can upload images with their titles and
>   later all the titles will become placeholder. User need to drag and
>   drop images on the correct placeholder to get points.
>
> This module is an attempt to enhance Quiz module features by
>   introducing another type of question.